# IllegalArgumentException: Not supported when implement sonarqube solution for "XML parsers should not be vulnerable to XXE attacks"

Tags: java, sonarqube, illegalargumentexception, xxe

I've this sonarqube issue in my java project: Disable access to external entities in XML parsing.
I've implemented the compliant solution that is like this:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

but now when i debug the code i've this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The implementation of Transformer Factory in your application may not support the properties XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET.

You can try creating instance of Transformer Factory in this way :

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl();
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

instead of your actual code :

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```